# Setting MaxJSONSerializer length to particular action in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Is it possible to set MaxJSONSerializer length for a particular action in MVC. I'm calling an Action method via ajax POST. And passing the parameter as object itself, so the call is not done it's showing

> The JSON request was too large to be deserialized.

. I know we can able to change the property in Web.config file. I want to know is there any possibilities to set it for the particular Action.
This is the ajax function i am using. If i have send smaller object array it is working. Here *settingobj* object is having the larger size:

```
$.ajax({
url: "Home/CreateNew", 
data:{ jobId: val, projectId: selectcaseid, userId: user.id(), objSetting: settingobj, custle: objcustle() },
type: "POST",
success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
        //Success function
    },
error: function(result){
        //error function
    }
});
```

Comment: please provide controller method where exception arrise, js looks fine

Answer (score 0):

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Params["custle"]);
    string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
    {
        // no JSON data
        return null;
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = 2147483647;
    object jsonData = serializer.DeserializeObject(bodyText);
    return jsonData;
```